# How to make a callable type safe?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-4

I can write a function like this:

```
func foo(someCallableThatShouldReturnBool: Callable):
    if someCallableThatShouldReturnBool.call(): # do something
```

unfortunately, the second line isn't type safe, since the Callable isn't guaranteed to return bool. Can I add type hints to ensure this callable is one that returns bool?

Comment: Are you asking about [this 4.x version of `Callable`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_callable.html)? And what does your declaration for `someCallableThatShouldReturnBool.call()` look like - does it include a return type in the declaration?

Comment: Yes, 4.x. The declaration for .call() _could_ have a return type defined, but it could just as quickly not, for example `foo(func(): 100)` would be valid, even though I don't want it to be.

Comment: As you are aware when declaring a `Callable` the type does include the signature type information of what it points so. Thus, right now there is no static solution (the type could be checked in runtime, but I as far as I can tell, that is not what you are looking for).